# How would I want to make a custom argument when making a function

Tags: c#, function, arguments

Im currently trying to make a custom argument in c# for cmd, This is my first time using c#.
I tried the attached code but it just opens the console window?

```
static void DoStuff(string args)
{
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = args;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
}

DoStuff("ping 127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: cmd.exe requires the `/c` flag to launch another command, but then `ping` is an executable in its own right (c:\windows\system32\ping.exe) so there's not much point launching cmd.exe to launch ping.exe when you could just directly launch ping.exe. Furthermore, there is a [`Ping` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-6.0) built into .NET, so you could do it natively within .NET code without invoking external programs.

Comment: I was mostly trying to make a function argument with the cmd.exe but thanks either way